# Wagtail dependency issue

Tags: wagtail, urllib3

Using Wagtail 1.13.1 we're suddenly getting an error when building locally using Docker, and the build fails.

```
Cannot uninstall 'urllib3' It is a distutils installed project and 
thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which 
would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Is urllib3 a dependency of Wagtail via Requests?

has anyone else experienced this?

Thanks

Joss

Comment: It looks like we were installing python-urllib3 with apt-get update && apt-get install in the DockerFile, once I removed this it was fine

Comment: Can you turn your comment into an answer and accept it? It is fine to answer your own question on SO.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like we were installing `python-urllib3` with `apt-get update && apt-get install` in the `DockerFile`; once I removed this, it was fine.